# Ajax Request being blocked by Cors when I abort or exit in the middle of the controller function

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, cors, nuxt.js

I recently started working on separate repositories for front-end and back-end by using Nuxt.js and Laravel. I have solved the Cors issue by creating a middleware.

However, it seems like some of my request still gets blocked by Cors when I try to abort, exit or die in the middle of the controller function... e.g. `dd('test!');`

P.S The requests are not blocked when I return the responses in correct json format.

- console error
  [image]
- network tab when error
  [image]
- network tab when no error
  [image]
  Please help!

Comment: What are the exact error messages that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: Hi I have added a few screenshots to see if they can help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to share what I found:

I think the middleware I created couldn't attach the headers because Laravel's `dd()` function terminates the entire request in the middle.
So I guess I will just have to make a habit to include the variable in the json response every time when there is a variable that I wanna dump out.

Please let me know if there is anyone with the better solution!